# Too many local variables in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I wrote a control, and use a tool to do the code analysis. There is a test that I didn't pass. Avoid excessive locals, http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182263(VS.90).aspx.

In my CreateChildControls function, I built a big table with lots of field. I need to create a  lot of TableRow and TableCell to construct the table. But these  are not field or property of control. Thery are local variables in the function, which are created dynamically.

Should I make these TableCells and TableRows as fields of the control? Or I just keep them as the local variables in the CreateChildControl function?

Best Regards,

Comment: The code is like what @codeka paste below. But I don't reuse local variables.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest that you consider using a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) control instead of dynamically creating lots of rows and cells in the backend code. By using a `Repeater`, you can more easily modify the actual markup without having to go through hundreds of lines of code to find it.

But if that's not an option, then consider the question: Do you actually need to have a *unique* variable for each one? Could you instead do something like this:

```
TableRow tr;
TableCell tc;

tr = new TableRow();
tc = new TableCell();
tc.Text = "whatever";
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
table.Rows.Add(tr);

tr = new TableRow();
tc = new TableCell();
tc.Text = "whatever # 2";
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
table.Rows.Add(tr);
```

That is, reuse the *same* variable for multiple rows/cells.

Comment: In most cases I would argue that reused local variables, which often have awful names like tr and tc, make for much less readable code than extra local variables with better names like whateverRow and anotherRow.

Comment: @dahlbyk: that can be true, too. To be honest, I was contemplating  leaving my answer at just "use `Repeater` instead", which is probably the better advice, long-term.

Comment: I don't need use the Repeater. Because the table is like a form, not for displaying data.

Answer (score 0):

Code analysis rules should always be used as a guideline - if you're satisfied with a solution that violates a rule, add an exception and move on to harder problems.

That said, eliminating local variables is often as easy as extracting methods (and classes if appropriate) to implement the desired logic. In your case, you may have a method to construct a `TableRow` which calls other methods to construct each `TableCell`. This has the additional benefit of making your `CreateChildControls` method easier to read and test.

**Update:** To answer your question about promoting the variables to fields, I would suggest avoiding fields unless they are absolutely necessary. In this case, they don't appear to be, so you would be better off keeping them as local within the relevant method.